# MSSQL ошибка OleDB provider

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, link

Есть база MSSQL 2017 c линкой на базу данных ORACLE.
так же установлен oracle cient на пк где MSSQL.

Делаю запрос Select * from table@link

Мне возвращает "Cannont Create an instance of OLE DB provider OraOledb Oraacle for linked server 'Linked'"

Погугли,сделал манипуляции.

- На провайдере OLEDB Oracle  поставил галочку Allow inproccess.
- Права доступа выдал по инструкции для MSDAINITIALIZE

Возвращает туже ошибку.

Фаервол и дотсуп в сети работает,проверял.
Пк в домене, но с правами админа,в чем может быьт еще причина?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

До установил компоненты как на скрине и все заработало.
Ключевым оказался Драйвер ORACLE ODBC

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]